# Composition of permutation group cycles

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Compute $gfg^{-1}$ if $f=(1,3,5,6)$ and $g=(2,5,4,6)$ where multiplicative notation is used to indicate composition and $f$ and $g$ are cycles.

I have determined $$g^{-1}= (2,6,4,5)$$ and thus found $$gfg^{-1}=(2,5,4,6)(1,3,5,6)(2,6,4,5)$$

This is where I am stuck, however. I do not know how to simplify this. I can do it with compositions of two cycles, but am unsure about this one as this is the composition of three cycles.

Comment: Do you compose from right to left, or from left to right?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - generally, in our textbook $g \circ f = g(f)$, so I assume right to left?

Comment: Looks like it, yes. I’ll write up a hint on that basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $1$, and ask what the composite permutation does to it: $g^{-1}$ does nothing, $f$ sends it to $3$, and $g$ does nothing to $3$, so $(gfg^{-1})(1)=3$. Do that for everything, and you have $gfg^{-1}$ in two-line form. Alternatively, proceed now to see what $gfg^{-1}$ does to $3$, and work your way around whatever cycle is generated. Then start with something outside the cycle and do it again. Repeat until everything’s been handled, and you have $gfg^{-1}$ in cycle notation.

Comment: Thank you! Using this, I get $gfg^{-1} = (1,3,4,2)$ ?

Comment: @DJS: Looks good! You’re welcome. (And please ignore the one-line paragraph that I deleted: I’d misread one of the permutations.)

Answer (score 2):

Compute what the new permutation does to each number from $1$ to $6$, then you can express it as a product of cycles.